# Trace / monitor a variable at runtime?

Tags: c#, memory, reflection, garbage-collection, runtime

I'm looking for a way to trace/monitor a variable at runtime (not for debugging) and throw certain events if it e.g. changes or falls out of the scope. Is there a .NET built-in way to do this? Like, not watching the variable itself and holding a reference to it, but the place in memory where it is allocated?

Ugly pseudo code:

```
public class Dummy {
    public void DummyMethod(int randomVar) {
        randomVar = 4;
    }
}

public class MyApp {
    static void Main() {
        var testVar = 1;
        SuperVariableWatcher.Watch(testVar);
        SuperVariableWatcher.NotifyOnChange += (sender, args) =>
           _logger.Write("variable bla bla has changed.");

        var dummy = new Dummy().DummyMethod(testVar);
             // since Dummy changes testVar, NotifyOnChange would now
             // be called, maybe with information about
             // who has changed it, what value did it contain before
    }
}
```

Of course I can hold a reference to it in `SuperVariableWatcher` and check for changes every nano-second, but even if it would work fast and reliable, I would then be unable to see if the variable is ready to be garbage-collected (because of no references to it) since I'd be the one that holds the reference.

I can think of something like *angularJS* `$watch`, however I'm not sure how it works internally.

Comment: sounds like a property and INotifyPropertyChanged might work

Comment: @Plutonix Unfortunately that's exactly how I'd not like to it, because then every instance, service, etc. needs to implement the interface and notify about changes by themselves. Imagine a variable that get's manipulated by 30 services in a row (e.g. a validation container that holds only the last validation result I'd like to watch), so every participating validator that holds a reference to the result needs to implement the interface and notify about changes.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of doing that would be to use a property with an notify-changed event. However, there is also a fundamental issue in your idea:

```
// since Dummy changes testVar, NotifyOnChange would now
// be called,
```

No, it won't; `testVar` **is not changed**. The `testVar` in `Main` is *completely different* to the `randomVar` in `DummyMethod`, and the change to `randomVar` *does not represent* a change to `testVar`. The parameter is a value, passed-by-value: it is a *copy of the value read from `testVar`*; it is not `testVar` itself.

In the general case: no, it is not possible to use .NET (without debugging APIs etc) to watch for changes to an arbitrary variable *just as a variable*. The same applies to fields too.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly the point I'm struggling with, since I'm interested in how e.g. a service might change the value (even if it's just a copy of it, since for me as a 'user', it is the same 'variable').

Comment: @xvdiff Fundamentally and importantly, no **it is not** the same 'variable'. That is an expectation failure. Again, the preferred way to do that would be to pass in an *object* that has a *property*, and have the property `set` raise an event.